# C# operator overloading == and pragma warnings 660 & 661 not overriding Equals and GetHashCode when irrelevant

Tags: c#, operator-overloading

Why does the C# compiler complain with pragma warning 660 & 661

- "FooClass" defines operator == or operator != but does not override Object.Equals(object o)
- "FooClass" defines operator == or operator != but does not override Object.GetHashCode()

When adding additional operators, such as:

`public static bool operator ==(FooClass foo, string fooId)`

I am **not** specifying

`public static bool operator ==(FooClass foo, FooClass foo2)`

Which this would make sense to override Object.Equals and GetHashCode.

Is this just a limitation in the compiler that it's not properly checking the arguments specified in the operator?

Comment: Does this have something to do with I can no longer do `foo == null` without doing `foo == (FooClass)null`?

Comment: The warning is correct. If you can equate FooClass with string then you can equate FooClass with an object. If you can equate FooClass with an object then you can equate a FooClass with a FooClass. In which case, you should have a GetHashcode that is correct.

Comment: @EricLippert and how does that relate to things like Guid("AAAA-AAAA") vs string "aaaa-aaaa" where these are equivalent in terms of FooClass. I certainly cannot influence the hashcode of these objects.

Comment: Suppose you have a FooClass, call it f, such that it is equal to a string s.  Is it not strange that `f == s` can be true but `f.Equals(s)` can be false? (Unfortunately we have no way of making `s.Equals(f)` true; equality is a bit messed up in .NET.)  Now suppose you decide that `f.Equals(s)` should be true. Would it not be strange that `setOfObjects.Contains(f)` could be true and `f == s` could be true but `setOfObjects.Contains(s)` is false? The point of these warnings is to tell you that your implementation of equality is creating surprising situations like these.

Comment: I would expect f.Equals(s) to return false (as it would). I didn't override casting, s can't be casted to FooClass, they're not interchangable, but they can be directly compared.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general guideline is doing `foo == bar` should return the same result as `foo.Equals(bar)`, that is the reason for the warning. It is a guideline, not a requirement, and that is why it is a warning instead of a error.

The 2nd warning is because of the rule that `if(foo.Equals(bar)) foo.GetHashCode() == bar.GetHashCode()`. If two objects are equal, their hash codes should also be equal. Many things in the .NET framework and 3rd party libraries rely on this so if you don't do it things like `Dictionary` that use `GetHashCode()` for lookups is going to break.

So if I can do

```
FooClass foo = new FooClass("Foo");
if(foo == "Foo")
{
   //...
}
```

I expect to be able to do

```
FooClass foo = new FooClass("Foo");
Hashtable hash = new Hashtable();
hash.Add(foo, "Bar");
var result = hash["Foo"];
```

Comment: The latter is a rule, not a guideline; equality of objects must imply equality of hash code. For the differences between the rules and the guidelines see http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/02/28/guidelines-and-rules-for-gethashcode.aspx

Comment: @EricLippert Edited to reflect that.

Comment: @EricLippert what if it's impossible? string, Guid, Guid? i doubt you can get the same hashcode for all 3 of those types. Yet for my needs the values of them are equivalent.

Comment: @ChrisMarisic In that case you should not overide `==` and instead either have custom methods to test each type or special `IComparer`s for each type

Comment: That's just painful and unnecessary work in both creation and usage.

Comment: I'm accepting this answer, I just don't agree with the premise of it. I think this was short sighted, comparability does not mean interchangability. And writing IComparers are just nonsense.

Comment: I agree writing IComparers is nonsence, IMHO the "correct" way to do this is add a `bool bar.EqualsFoo(Foo obj)` call and do the comparison that way. That way you don't have the gotchas of needing to override stuff like `GetHashCode()`, `==` not matching `Equals(object)`, or `bar == foo` being a different result than `foo == bar`.